# Cómo puedo ver el dato solicitado por URL usando MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Aquí estoy solicitando al usuario que está en la base de datos MySQL, pero a la hora de querer mostrar en la web, no se muestra nada.

Código:

```js
router.get('/:id', async function(req, res) {
 
    const pusermane = req.params.id;
    if(!pusermane) return res.redirect('/')
    
      req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = ?', [pusermane], (err, usuario) => {
         if (err) {
          res.json(err);
         }
         res.render('usuarios/index', {
          login: req.isAuthenticated() ? "si" : "no",
          status: req.isAuthenticated() ? "PERFIL" : "LOGIN",
          loginp: (req.isAuthenticated() ? true : false),
          data: usuario
        })
    });
  });
})
```

Aquí muestro el código de lado del cliente donde estoy mostrando su perfil de usuario.

**Front-end:**

```
<div class="rowContentTwo">

  <div class="avauser">
  
    <img class="circle responsive-img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/<%= data.id_user %>/<%= data.avatar %>.png">
    <h3><%= data.username %></h3>
    
</div>
```

Comment: ¿qué información tiene la variable `data: usuario` y `data.username`?, ¿la respuesta de `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username =...` si trae datos?

Comment: Si hay datos y los muestra en consola